# ASP.NET MVC 6 Not Rendering CSS Style Sheet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get add a css file to my layout file, which is in the Shared folder. When I run the web application, my CSS is not rendered (CSS that is not in the solution (ie: Bootstrap CDN) renders.

I have tried linking the CSS using these methods, and they don't work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Assets/Scripts/StyleSheet.css")" type="text/css"/> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Assets/Scripts/StyleSheet.css" type="text/css"/>
```

The File Structure For my app is:

[image]

Is there something I should be adding to the Startup.cs file so it can read css files?

Thanks.

**EDIT: ERROR 404 WITH THE STYLE SHEET**

I ran the application on Mozilla Firefox, and used the built in Developers Console to see whats happening. After observing the network tab, it tells me ERROR 404 Occurred while trying to retrieve the style sheet. This is really odd.

[image]

Comment: I checked the Developer Console on Mozilla Firefox, and saw Errror 404 occurred when trying to retrieve the style sheet (see image above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Reference to a similar problem posted on StackOverflow: [ASP.NET 5 MVC6 Custom CSS & Javascript placing convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960538/asp-net-5-mvc6-custom-css-javascript-placing-convention)

I placed the CSS File in the wwwroot directory, in a css folder.

[image]

Then, in my Layout file, I changed the href attribute:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("../css/style.css")"/>
```

Finally, I made sure I had app.UseStaticFiles() in my Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(config => config.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            template: "{Controller}/{action}/{id?}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"}               
            ));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do other changes in your layout show up correctly?  For instance if you add a random text string, does that show up?  As far as startup.cs, you should have `app.UseStaticFiles();` in the Configure section.

Once more note, my CSS in the _layout looks like this:

```
<environment names="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
```

I don't think it's required to be broken out, but I haven't tried it not broken out...

Comment: Hi. Text on my layout page does appear on my other pages. Classes that I use from the bootstrap css work (the files are hosted on MaxCDN). I have checked my Startup.cs file, and in the Configure method, I do have app.UseStaticFiles().

Comment: First, check the generated html to see what it shows for the css url - it should not contain the "~".   Take the url from the page and try and go to that in your browser using the relative path as specified in the css url.   If all that looks good, use a browser tool such as firebug or chrome developer tools to determine what is being requested and how  the server is responding.

Comment: I have checked this with the browser - It says the style sheets cannot be found. This is odd because I am sure the style sheet is in the correct location.